# update query not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have this simple update query :

```sql
update `table_name` set `count` = `count` + 1 where `id` = '$id'
```

But every time i reload the page the count is incremented by 2 in the db. What is going on here? Thanks..

Comment: are you running the query twice by mistake? post more of your code, hard to tell from what you've given us what's wrong.

Comment: check it manually in mysql...

Comment: i have checked it manually in mysql its working fine .

Comment: are you running this in loop?

Comment: no if my query is running twice then when i echo it, it should display twice right?

Comment: then you must share your complete code of query.....

Comment: can you write echo query

Comment: please show your PHP page where you have used the query. And show us how you're invoking it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a browser issue. Your browser visit page twice.

Why it could be:

- Your page contains `img` or `script` without or empty `src` attr.
- Request to favicon lead to your page.
- Your browser has extension which send extra requests.
- Your css contains something like this: `{background-image: url();}`

Explore your browser console for requests.

Comment: i have fixed an empty src attribute but its still not working and this issue is there in all the browsers so it is certainly not a extension issue

Comment: Check your requests with browser console

Answer (score 1):

Try Below Code :
Fetch count first from that table and increment it and then update the table

```
$count = SELECT count(*) FROM `table_name`
$count1 = $count + 1;
update `table_name` set `count` = '$count1' where `id` = '$id'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring a variable before you call it in the query like this : 
Also im not sure if your 'count' is a string or also a variable.

```
$count2 = 'count' + 1;
update `table_name` set `count` = '$count2' where `id` = '$id'
```

Comment: count is the mysql column name

Comment: Im asking of the second 'count' in this statement "set 'count' = 'count' + 1". You can't directly fetch any column and it's value unless you have an sql query before update query of yours.

Comment: What im trying to say is just like "you could try to fetch count first from that table , increment it and then update the table".